# Why does reduction always accompany oxidation and vice versa?

Tags: redox

We've all learnt that the reduction always accompanies oxidation and vice versa Why is this so? Why is it not possible that a species releases an electron and the electron just "floats around"? Is this related to the stability of a free electron?

Comment: @Asker123 So there are **highly** unfavourbale cases where this happens? Can you provide an example?

Comment: My bad, there are no **highly** unfavorable cases. Even then, there must be an outside cause.

Answer (score 2):

If something is to be **reduced** then there must be a **reducing agent** present. Also if something is **oxidized** then there must be an **oxidizing agent** present.

You must have a **reducing agent** or **oxidizing agent** present in order for a redox reaction to take place. An element can't just dislocate it's electrons. There must be an outside force present in order to do that.

Comment: Let's say I supply a lot of heat to a sodium atom. Why can't the electron be ejected and remain as such **without** reducing any of the species present in the environment?

Comment: The outside force in this situation is **heat**. Of course this can happen, but however I doubt that the electrons will just remain present in the environment for long. Theoretically, yes it is possible.

Comment: Is there any example you can provide where electrons remain present in the environment for long (theroretical or experimental)?